# How to build boost static libs?

Tags: c++, boost, static-libraries, bjam

This works, but doesn't build static versions of boost libraries (maybe i am wrong?)

```
bjam --toolset=gcc --prefix=C:\boost_1_49_0-mingw install
```

Trying to issue folloving command:

```
bjam --toolset=gcc --prefix=C:\boost_1_49_0-mingw --build-type=complete install
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 23):

You should be able to use the `link=static` option to let you compile the library into your binary without needing the dynamic lib:

```
sudo ./b2 link=static
```

Check your stage directory to make sure it goes in the right spot and then re-install to whatever system directory you include.