# Missing boost library

Tags: c++, boost

My VSC2013 compiler wants me to link to `libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-1_55.lib` but that file doesn't exist in `boost\stage\lib`. I only have lib files ending in `vc120-mt-1_55.lib` and `vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib`

I built boost with

```
bootstrap
b2
```

What do I need to do to get the lib above?

Edit: this worked

`b2 variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static`

Comment: Try a "debug" build `libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib` should be good to go

Comment: mt : Multi threading,
s: Static,
gd: ABI with debug version,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014517/whats-the-difference-between-mt-gd-and-mt-s-library

Comment: @P0W A "debug" build of my program compiles just fine, but I need to get the "release" build working too. For that, the compiler insists on the aforementioned file.

Comment: @A.B. add option `variant=debug,release` while building see `./b2 --help` for details

Comment: add `link=static runtime-link=static` to b2 line.

Comment: After running that command, you can use the Boost lib??

Answer (score 2):

You should build *static* version of boost libraries. See this question [How to build boost static libs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751271/how-to-build-boost-static-libs)

NOTE:
Libraries naming convention:

- mt : Multi threading
- s: Static
- gd: ABI with debug version,

See this question to know [what's the difference between mt-gd and mt-s library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014517/whats-the-difference-between-mt-gd-and-mt-s-library)

Comment: How does one do that?